# What is the expiry of property we set using d Properties.setProperty(key, value) method of Class PropertiesService

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

I am unable to find what is the expiry of property we set using Properties.setProperty(key, value) method of Class PropertiesService.
I know we can delete it using `deleteProperty(key)`.

example: `var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); userProperties.setProperty('userEmail', "user@xyz.com");`

When the value of userEmail will be removed from the storage if we don't delete it using `deleteProperty(key)` method?

Comment: Why do you suppose there is an expiry time for [`Properties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)? If that behavior is not reflected in the documentation,  there is no point to think otherwise. Have you seen that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In the current state there does not appear to be an `Expiration Time` property within the `Service Properties`, this would need to be set manually. Something like this:

```js
const EXPIRY_TIME_KEY = "expiryTime"
const HAS_ACCESS_KEY = "hasAcces"
const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()

function isExpired() {
  const expProp = userProperties.getProperty(EXPIRY_TIME_KEY)
  const checkerTimer = (new Date().getTime() - expProp) / 1000
  /* 1 hour timer */
  if(checkerTimer > 3600){
    userProperties.setProperty(HAS_ACCESS_KEY, false)
  }
}

function grantAcces() {
  userProperties.setProperty(EXPIRY_TIME_KEY, new Date().getTime())
  userProperties.setProperty(HAS_ACCESS_KEY, true)
}
```

If you want to add this functionality to Google Apps Script, you can make a feature request using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your properties to expire, just use CacheService. Properties are bounded to the doc / script / user and don't have an expiration time.

Example of cache usage:

```
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();    

cache.put("cache-prop", cacheContent, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes (in seconds)
```

"The data you write to the cache is not guaranteed to persist until its expiration time. You must be prepared to get back null from all reads."

About CacheService
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service

About Cache Class
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache